# На Iphone не применяются изменения файла hosts

Tags: ios, iphone, hosts

Решил сделать джейлбрейк Iphone 6s ios 15.2 Для моего аппарата подходил только полупривязанный джейлбрейк от palera1n.
После того как значок palera1n появился решил через filza поменять файл `/private/etc/hosts` используя Webdav. Для удобства поменял файл: `master.passwd` и установил пароль для пользователя root. Изменения сработали. Теперь я могу подключиться как по WinSCP так и через Putty. Проблема в том что какие бы сайты я не вносил в файл hosts они не применяются, то есть как Safari так и Firefox продолжают их открывать игнорируя файл hosts.
Вот такой файл hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1   local
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
127.0.0.1   www.youtube.com
::1 www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   m.youtube.com
::1 m.youtube.com
127.0.0.1   dzen.ru
::1 dzen.ru
```

Судя по этому хосту не должны открываться Youtube и Дзен, но они спокойно продолжают работать.
В чем может быть проблема? Заранее благодарен за ответ.